# Segmentation fault in function that reads file and with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, filereader

I am having a problem writing a function that will be passed to a pthread_create. The function takes two arguments. I am getting segmentation fault while calling it.

And pthread_create:

```
pthread_create(&tid_array[i], NULL, searchForWord(argv[i + 2], word), &wData[i]);
```

Can function passed to pthread_create take other arguments than void *?

Answer (score 2):

pthread_create takes a start routine, in the form of a function pointer.

The expression `searchForWord(argv[i + 2], word)` is not a function pointer; it calls searchForWord in the current thread, which always returns NULL, and then passes NULL to pthread_create.

The thread start function must take a pointer-to-void parameter, but you are free to create a struct, pass a pointer to that struct into the function. You'll get a pointer-to-void, which you can cast to pointer-to-your-struct.

Comment: @hello no, you should be passing a function pointer: `searchForWord` by itself is the syntax. You'll need to pass `argv[i+2]` using that void pointer parameter made available by pthread_create.

Comment: @helloworld, It sounds like you might need to study up more on the concept of _[expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science))_. `searchForWord` is a _[primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_primitive)_ expression. Its value is a constant—a pointer to the searchForWord function, which is what you want to pass to `pthread_create`. `searchForWord(argv[i+2],word)` is a _compound_ expression, made from the expressions `searchForWord`, `argv[i+2]`, and `word`. Its value is computed at run-time by _calling_ the searchForWord function.